# Nested Checkbox with 2 levels using Chakra-ui (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-state-management, chakra-ui

I'm trying to build a nested checkbox with 2 levels using Chakra-UI.

- Once clicked on parent checkbox, all children should be checked: (v)
- if you click on one child, all parents should be on indeterminate state: (-)
- if all children are checked, the parent of these children should be checked as well.

The first level is already done here:

[image: Nested Checkbox with 2 level using Chakra-ui]

```
import React from "react";
import { Checkbox, Stack, Box } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const data = {
users: [
{
  id: "user-1",
  name: "User 1",
  child: [{ name: "Salary1" }, { name: "Department1" }]
},
{
  id: "user-2",
  name: "User 2",
  child: [{ name: "Salary2" }, { name: "Department2" }]
},
{
  id: "user-3",
  name: "User 3",
  child: [{ name: "Salary3" }, { name: "Department3" }]
},
{
  id: "user-4",
  name: "User 4",
  child: [{ name: "Salary4" }, { name: "Department4" }]
},
{
  id: "user-5",
  name: "User 5",
  child: [{ name: "Salary5" }, { name: "Department5" }]
},
{
  id: "user-6",
  name: "User 6",
  child: [{ name: "Salary6" }, { name: "Department6" }]
},
{
  id: "user-7",
  name: "User 7",
  child: [{ name: "Salary7" }, { name: "Department7" }]
},
{
  id: "user-8",
  name: "User 8",
  child: [{ name: "Salary8" }, { name: "Department8" }]
}
 ]
};

export default function App() {
const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = React.useState(
  data.users.map(() => false)
 );

const allChecked = checkedItems.every(Boolean);
const isIndeterminate = checkedItems.some(Boolean) && !allChecked;

return (
  <Stack pt={3} pl={3}>
  <Checkbox
    isChecked={allChecked}
    isIndeterminate={isIndeterminate}
    onChange={(e) =>
      setCheckedItems(data.users.map(() => e.target.checked))
    }
  >
    Parent Checkbox
  </Checkbox>

  <Stack pl={6} mt={2} spacing={2}>
    {data.users.map((user, index) => (
      <Box key={user.id}>
        <Checkbox
          key={user.id}
          isChecked={checkedItems[index]}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setCheckedItems([
              ...checkedItems.slice(0, index),
              e.target.checked,
              ...checkedItems.slice(index + 1)
            ])
          }
        >
          {user.name}
        </Checkbox>
        <Stack pl={6} spacing={2}>
          {user.child.map((category) => (
            <Checkbox key={category.name}>{category.name}</Checkbox>
          ))}
        </Stack>
      </Box>
    ))}
  </Stack>
</Stack>
);
```

How could the level 2 be achieved using the starter code above?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the **CodeSanbox link**: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-rosalind-741e5c?file=/src/App.js:0-2336